# Postfix Questions

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat, email-server

Kindly find your help on the below,

I'm a beginner and I've Bulk of questions.

I've downloaded postfix 2.10.2.tar.gz to install on RHEL server 5.9.
Installation will be performed via source code.

I need to modify basic paths settings,

1 - I installed SW.

2 - Edited paths in /etc/postfix/main.cf after installation.

3 - Moving files to new paths.

4 - Running postfix start >> I've this error message " no such file/directory /etc/postfix/main.cf which is the original sample directory.

I tried another approach,

1 - Configure main.cf before installation with needed paths.

2 - install SW

3 - Strange settings in main.cf happened :D .. sample directory /etc/postfix which is the original setting get back and take place of my modified path same happened with /var/spool/postfix

- How can I modify paths please ? Don't ask me why :D ?
- I've postfix 2.3 installed on other machine, running find / -name postfix .. I found different paths 
   For Example:
       - in postfix 2.3 we've:
             /usr/sbin/postfix

  ```
         /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/postfix

         /usr/libexec/postfix

         /var/lib/postfix

         /var/spool/postfix

         /var/lock/subsys/postfix

         /etc/rc.d/init.d/postfix

         /etc/postfix

    - in postfix 2.10 we don't have the following:

         /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/postfix

         /usr/libexec/postfix

         /var/lock/subsys/postfix

         /etc/rc.d/init.d/postfix
  ```

I hope to find your help/explanation for this difference, Am I installed anything wrong ?

My last Question is : How to uninstall it as it's installed via source code ?
   - I always ran "make tidy"

- then delete files by hand

I need you also to validate this :)

Sorry for long story & thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

most likely you will find all these changes in the release notes of postfix in the corresponding releases or in between. so as a wise senior admin said to me.. (many many times) ;) **RTFM**

another tip for when compiling from source is that you run the ./configure command with a --prefix option. so it will put the software you made in a single directory tree and not spread around the operating system. Compiling with a prefix will help you a lot if u made a booboo and u realized it after running the make install command.

Maybe check out the ./configure --help it will show you that it has an armada of options to influence paths or options you want or dont want in your software.

Why dont you make life a lot easier and install postfix via yum (in case of redhat it requires a rhn subscription). Seeing you are a beginner you might be putting yourself a little bit in to deep. If there isnt a really good reason for compiling from source you should probably just steer away from it. It makes patch management difficult and annoying. a good postfix configuration in itself is already a challenge ;)

Answer (score 1):

*STOP*

Don't install postfix from source, use the RPMs RHEL provides. That way you get a working config, security updates and Red Hat support. And given that you're so far out of your depth on this one, any one of these reasons should be good enough.

Comment: I am sorry but this is the case :(

And I've to fix the above issues:

1- modify directories to my own.

2- How to uninstall ?

3- feel frightened from not finding postfix under some paths as mentioned above.

any advices ?

Comment: reinstall the box?

Comment: Can you validate my wat to uninstall first, please ?